How Should I show that these $k$-algebras are not Isomorphic?
Question
Show that the $k$-algebras $k[x,y]/\langle xy \rangle$ and $k[x,y]/\langle xy-1 \rangle$ are not isomorphic.
Attempt
At first, I thought $xy=0$. This would mean both $x$ and $y$ are zero divisors. Also, for $xy=1$, then $x$ and $y$ are inverses of each other. Hence, the $k$-algebras are not isomorphic. However, considering we are dealing with equivalence classes and not elements $x$ and $y$, this approach may be wrong.
So my question is, how can I go about this problem since what we have here is a case of equivalence classes of $x$ and $y$, and not elements $x$ and $y$.

Hint: One of them is an integral domain, the other one is not.

You are on the right track but an isomorphism need not send the $x$ in the first algebra to the $x$ in the second algebra and vice versa. So you need to show that either the second one has no zero divisors or that the first one has no nontrivial invertible elements (I mean other than the ones in $k$).

Regarding your attempt, you are correct that $k[x,y]/(xy)$ consists of equivalence classes, and so it is not formally correct to write something like $x\in k[x,y]/(xy)$. Nevertheless, it is common to abuse notation and conflate a polynomial $f\in k[x,y]$ with its image in $k[x,y]/(xy)$, i.e. the equivalence class $[f]=f+(xy)$. People often intuitively think of the quotient ring $R/I$ as being the "same" as $R$, except that all elements of $I$ have been set to zero.

You are on the right track. We have that $(x + \langle xy \rangle)(y + \langle xy \rangle) = xy + \langle xy \rangle = 0 +\langle xy \rangle$ so $x + \langle xy \rangle$ and $y + \langle xy \rangle$ are zero divisors. However, simply showing that $xy + \langle xy - 1 \rangle = 1 + \langle xy - 1\rangle$ is not enough. Here, you are only showing that the map defined by $x + \langle xy \rangle \mapsto x + \langle xy - 1\rangle$ and $y + \langle xy \rangle \mapsto y + \langle xy-1 \rangle$ is not an isomorphism. (In fact, this map is not even a homomorphism since $0 +\langle xy \rangle \mapsto 1 + \langle xy-1 \rangle$.)
To show that no isomorphism exists, you can show that $k[x,y]/\langle xy-1\rangle$ has no zero divisors as @Mark suggests in the comments. To do this, you will need to show that $\langle xy - 1\rangle$ is a prime ideal. This post may help.
